# "Protein suckers attached to the teleology" in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow

Tags: meaning, e-l-doctorow, andrews-brain

I'm reading *Andrew's Brain* by E. L. Doctorow. In this paragraph I have some difficulties:

> I’m just thinking of something I read about the pathogenesis of
> schizophrenia and bipolar disease. The brain biologists are going to
> get to that with their gene sequencing, finding the variations in the
> genome — **those protein suckers attached to the teleology**. They’ll give
> them numbers and letters, snipping away a letter here, adding a number
> there, and behold the disease will be no more. So, Doc, you’re in
> trouble with your talking cure.

I don't get the bolded phrase "**those protein suckers attached to the teleology**". Does anyone know its meaning?

Comment: It sounds like a typo for "telomeres" (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41380-022-01541-7).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I doubt it. It is possible to make sense of the sentence as currently written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Teleology** has a long history in biology. Before Darwin, biology and other sciences attributed natural phenomena to design. For example, the theologian [Hugh of St. Victor](https://crev.info/scientists/hugh-of-st-victor/), "Nature is a book written by the hand of God" (some sources say "the finger of God"). Darwin's theory of evolution challenged this by attributing natural variations to chance rather than design.

However, **even after Darwin teleology has not completely disappeared from biology**. At the very least, Darwin's theory challenged "strong teleology" (such as the theological version mentioned above), but this should be distinguished from "weak teleology", which is descriptive. Darwin and many of his successors never divorced themselves entirely from teleological language.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5H8r.jpg)

This is a rather long preamble to explain why "teleology" is probably not a typo for "telomeres" (as one comment assumed) and to the **dichotomy between two views on mental disorder** that are referred to in the passage from *Andrew's Brain*. The dichotomy is one between biological explanations of mental disorder, presumably based on genes that are there for some "purpose" (hence "teleology") [2], and between purely psychological or perhaps social factors on the other. The "talking cure" would be rejected if a purely biological or genetic explanation for schizophrenia and bipolar disorder were found. These mental disorders would then come to be regarded as part of naturally occurring diversity ("and behold the disease will be no more").

The passage from the novel does not tell us whether the speaker has strong or weak teleology in mind, or whether they are even aware of the distinction. The text can also be interpreted as presenting a [**false binary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma): either those mental disorder have a psychological or social cause, in which case psychological treatment (the "talking cure") is appropriate, or their cause is genetic, in which case the psychological treatment is pointless. In light of theories about [gene–environment interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene%E2%80%93environment_interaction), this assumption may be wrong.

The other part of the phrase is **protein suckers**. "Sucker" is a pun: one the one hand it is a disrespectful term for "a naive or gullible person" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sucker)), on the other hand it refers to a piece of lab equipment for extracting samples from fluids. There was a time when researchers actually needed to suck on a tube, i.e. do [mouth pipetting](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/suck-it-the-ins-and-outs-of-mouth-pipetting) (see the image below). This is now considered unsafe, and there are many safe [alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipette#Common_pipettes). (See [When did mouth pipetting stop becoming a way to handle liquids in a lab?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/36588) on Biology Stack Exchange.)

[image: black and white photo of a female lab worker sucking on a tube to extract liquid from a test tube]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5H8r.jpg) The German physicist and philosopher Gerhard Vollmer explains how such language is to be interpreted (page 234). When biologists say, for example, "The cow has an udder *in order that*, when she has a calf, she can feed her offspring", this is really shorthand for "The cow has an udder *because* those ancestors who had a genetic constitution for an udder were better able to feed their offspring and thus pass on their genes to the next generation".

[2] I'm not sure the speaker wants to imply that schizophrenia and bipolar disorder have a biological purpose; they may also think that these mental disorders, I have they have a genetic source, might be by-products of genetic changes they regard otherwise beneficial. (Quite possibly, this has become a much more touchy subject in the context of more recent debates about [neurodiversity](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/neurodiverse-age/201907/mental-disorder-within-the-neurodiversity-paradigm).)

**References**:

- Allen, Colin; Neal, Jacob: ["Teleological Notions in Biology"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/teleology-biology/), Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, 2020.
- Flannery, Michael A.: ["Strong and Weak Teleology in the Life Sciences Post-Darwin"](https://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/11/6/298/htm). *Religions* 2020, 11, 298. (Open Access)
- Vollmer, Gerhard: *Im Lichte der Evolution. Darwin in Wissenschaft und Philosophie*. S. Hirzel, 2017.

Comment: I agree that it’s most likely not a typo, and with all your explanation, but I also don’t think the similarity to *telomeres* is irrelevant: I’d read this as a deliberate play on words, meant to give the attentive reader a slight double-take.  The aptness in context — a near-pun between conceptual and biochemical meanings, in a discussion of the ambiguity between psychological and biochemical mechanisms — seems too good to be coincidental.